# python generator that starts at n and loops in reverse?

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to find a highest common factor and want to start at the upper end, How can I create a  generator in python that starts at n and decrements by -1?

```
def drange(end):
   i = 1
   while  i > end:
      yield i
      i += 1
```

Comment: it starts with a very large number so using xrange gives me the error OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Comment: This does not sound like an effective way to compute GCDs. Why not use the Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, the question is not about the error, it is asking how to create a generator that counts backwards from n, i have coded a generator that increments without any error, I just wondered if there was a way to do it in reverse.

Comment: @user2357112, You are correct, it was just a thought I had and wondered if it were possible, it is for my own curiosity more than anything.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: that post gives you a generic generator that will count down. Generators *only go forward* but forward can mean producing numbers in decreasing order.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Why not show us your code for your forward generator?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: and using `i = end`, `while i > -1:` and `i -= 1` is not an obvious adjustment?

Comment: You can write a generator and are not able to use subtraction instead of addition? Truly, this world is full of wonders.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 you can use

```
reversed(range(1000000000000000000000))
```

This works because the range object has a `__reversed__` method.

Python 2's xrange can't handle numbers that big, so you'll need a generator function:

```
def downrange(n):
    while n > 0:
        yield n
        n -= 1

for i in downrange(n):
    print i
```

Answer (score 1):

Your generator is easily adapted:

```
def drange(end):
    i = end
    while i > 0:
        yield i
        i -= 1
```

This counts down from `end` to 1:

```
>>> def drange(end):
...     i = end
...     while i > 0:
...         yield i
...         i -= 1
... 
>>> for n in drange(3):
...     print n
... 
3
2
1
```

If you want to count down to 0, test for `i > -1`.

Comment: Why are you proposing a Generator, when something similar is already in itertools?

Comment: @Abhijit: Because the OP is asking about how to code this themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer I can think of is to use [itertools.count](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> p = count(10**10,-1)
>>> next(p) # Gives you the reverse decremented generator
```